# How to assert which coroutine dispatcher is used in unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I have a class to unit test that has 2 dispatchers injected, one that is `Dispatchers.Main` and one that is `Dispatchers.IO`. My code switches between these two via `withContext()` at some point and then switches back via `.collect()`. I would like my unit test for this code to make an assertion on what dispatcher I am supposed to be on. My test code currently just uses two instances of `TestCoroutineDispatcher`.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

One *ok* thing I have tried is modifying my production code to include `launch(mainDispatcher + CoroutineName("someUniqueName")) { ... }` where I can then assert on looking for the substring in `Thread.currentThread().name` in my unit test, but it really does not feel ideal and rather hacky to modify my prod code just for that.

Comment: Try with `coroutineContext[ContinuationInterceptor]!! == Dispatchers.IO`

Comment: Nice, this is much better. I notice that because I am passing two instances of `TestCoroutineDispatcher` in my tests in place of IO and Main, there is not a good way to differentiate between them using this method; do you perhaps know a good way to match which is which?